# Releasing objects in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift and am wondering if anyone can anyone help confirm my understanding with releasing objects in Apple's Swift?

The documentation for `CGPathCreateWithRect()` described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathCreateWithRect) states that the return value is

> "A new, immutable path. You are responsible for releasing this
>   object."

When is says "you are responsible" is it as simple as saying that when you no longer hold a reference the garbage collector will delete the object? I.e. you are responsible for managing the references? In which case - isn't that obvious? If not - what does it mean?

Thanks

Bryon

Comment: There is no `Garbage collector` in Swift. Read this to more understand how its works: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID48

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*You are responsible* only when using Objective-C

From the [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-ID61)

> **Memory Managed Objects**
>
> Core Foundation objects returned from annotated APIs are automatically
>   memory managed in Swift—you do not need to invoke the CFRetain,
>   CFRelease, or CFAutorelease functions yourself.

Comment: Thanks Vadian. After a bunch of reading up and some testing this appears to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

There is no garbage collection in iOS. Please refer to the apple docs on [memory management](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) and the concept of [ARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting) to better understand that comment and the paradigm shift here.

Also, in Swift you should not need to use this. You can create an actual object and pass the contained CGPathRef to any low level functions that may need it.

Answer (score 1):

You should really check out the ARC videos from WWDC 2011. They are available on the developer site and open through iTunes. Especially:

> • Session 323 – Introducing Automatic Reference Counting
>
> • Session 322 – Objective-C Advancements in Depth

Also, the ARC reference notes:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html

Both the reference notes and the videos discuss Core Graphics (et al) and how they work with ARC.

Specifically, look at the section called "Managing Toll-Free Bridging"

> In many Cocoa applications, you need to use Core Foundation-style
>   objects, whether from the Core Foundation framework itself (such as
>   CFArrayRef or CFMutableDictionaryRef) or from **frameworks that adopt
>   Core Foundation conventions such as Core Graphics** (you might use
>   types like CGColorSpaceRef and CGGradientRef).
>
> The compiler does not automatically manage the lifetimes of Core
>   Foundation objects; you must call CFRetain and CFRelease (or the
>   corresponding type-specific variants) as dictated by the Core
>   Foundation memory management rules (see Memory Management Programming
>   Guide for Core Foundation).
>
> If you cast between Objective-C and Core Foundation-style objects, you
>   need to tell the compiler about the ownership semantics of the object
>   using either a cast (defined in objc/runtime.h) or a Core
>   Foundation-style macro (defined in NSObject.h): [...]